# Simple math on entire sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, view, case

Lets take this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE correlation ( '1' REAL, '2' REAL, '3' REAL)
INSERT INTO correlation VALUES ( 1.0 , -0.4 , 0.6 )
INSERT INTO correlation VALUES ( -0.4 , 1.0 , 0.2 )
INSERT INTO correlation VALUES ( 0.6 , 0.2 , 1.0 )
```

Now want to create a view and do some simple math on the cells:

```
CREATE VIEW correlation_codes AS SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN * > 0 THEN 3
WHEN * < 0 THEN 5
WHEN * == 0 THEN 8
WHEN * == 1.0 THEN 4
ELSE 99
END
FROM correlation
```

The desired result:

```
 1.0  -0.4  0.6
-0.4   1.0  0.2
 0.6   0.2  1.0
```

becomes:

```
 4      5     3
 5      4     3
 3      3     4
```

I cannot use * in CASE, but I want one CASE for the entire table.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you using numbers (well, okay, strings that can be directly cast to numbers) as column names?  That's just asking for trouble, especially in `where` or `group by` statements (`WHERE '1'>0` looks wonky at best).

Secondly, you're correct in that you can't use `*` in a `case` statement.  You'll have to run the `case` statement on each column separately and make a table out of all of them.  However, it doesn't seem to work when the column names are (essentially) numbers:

`select case
when '1'>0 then 3
when '1'<0 then 5
when '1'==0 then 8
when '1'==1.0 then 4
else 99
end
from correlation;`

yields

```
3
3
3
```

Instead, let's try sensible column names:

```
sqlite> create table correlation2 (c1 real,c2 real,c3 real);
sqlite> insert into correlation2 values (1.0,-0.4,0.6);
sqlite> insert into correlation2 values (-0.4,1.0,0.2);
sqlite> insert into correlation2 values (0.6,0.2,1.0);
```

Now, the case statement gives:

```
sqlite> select case when c1>0 then 3 when c1<0 then 5 when c1==0 then 8 when c1==1.0 then 4 else 99 end from correlation2;
case when c1>0 then 3 when c1<0 then 5 when c1==0 then 8 when c1==1.0 then 4 else 99 end
3
5
3
```

Now, you wanted the column values to be

```
4
5
3
```

However, that's not how the case statement works:  Since 1.0>1, the first branch of the case statement is evaluated (and hence the first entry is assigned to 3, not 4).  Is this what you meant?

```
sqlite> select case when c1>0 and c1!=1 then 3 when c1<0 then 5 when c1==0 then 8 when c1==1 then 4 else 99 end from correlation2;
case when c1>0 and c1!=1 then 3 when c1<0 then 5 when c1==0 then 8 when c1==1 then 4 else 99 end
4
5
3
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, forget about the number for column names, I would like to avoid creating a long case statement. My table is essentially a matrix, and I would like to do a transformation on it, and store the result in a view. The transformation is the same for all elements in the matrix/table.

Comment: Getting a database to think of a table as a matrix is usually difficult at best.  If you have a fixed number of columns for your table, then you can just run `select <case statement for the first column>,<case statement for the second column>,<case statement for the third column> from correlations2;`.  If your table doesn't have a static number of columns, then you can either write a function via the SQLite C/++ API or do the transformation in a scripting language before sending the data to SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a UDF and run each column through the UDF, to do the transformation. I think you can use the UDF in a view:

```
           create view myView as
           select udf(col1), udf(col2), udf(col3) ...
           from T
```